# Vectorized `cross` function in Python

Tags: python, pine-script

Pinescript offers the `cross` [function](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v1/#fun_cross) that will return `True` if two Series cross each other.

In python we could achieve the same easily for let's say two MA-s with a `for` loop and `if` statement. How can we vectorize this operation?

Specifically what is almost close to what I want:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1], 'b': [2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]})
np.where(d.a < d.b, True, False)
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True,  True])
```

But from my understanding in Pinescript we would have a signal only at the exact crossover point.

```
array([ False,  False, True, False,  True,  False])
```

Comment: You could try comparing adjacent signs of the `a - b`: `np.diff(np.sign(d.a - d.b), prepend=d.a[0] - d.b[0]) != 0`. I haven't tested this against Pinescript, but the output matches in this example.

Comment: this makes sense, and at first sight, it seems that it should work OK, unless I'm mistaken. Let's make it into an answer.

Comment: I hesitate to post an answer as this might not handle corner cases. For example, when `d.a` and `d.b` are equal, the code above will report no intersections. I am not sure what the intended output of `cross` is.

Comment: Its documentation on Pinescript's documentation is a bit sparse it's true. I am not sure if they consider the two series as crossing each other if the become equal. I personally would say that yes there should be a True value in that case.